# How does browser post values that are not present in the dom

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, browser, webforms

I have spent whole day searching for the answer but could not find any. When I use chrome browser inspector I can see following fields being posted.

> __EVENTTARGET:
>
> __EVENTARGUMENT:
>
> __VIEWSTATE:'-----------LONG LONG-----------'

which I can find inside the Dom, all are hidden fields
But the browser is still sending following fields

> ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$imgbSearch.x:37
>
> ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$imgbSearch.y:9

These are completely not present in the Dom not even those values.

what I could find was

```
<div class="buttonBox">
                <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$imgbSearch" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_imgbSearch" src="Images/Buttons/Find.jpg" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$imgbSearch&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;SearchPanel&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" />
            </div>
```

So can you please help me find how this happened. How do I get those missing fields and values

Comment: Specifically to how .NET does it, I'm not sure, but you (or .net) could create them in javascript before the form is submitted.

Comment: not sure what you mean, but even if javascript is disabled, those values are being posted

Comment: so the onclick event of that image button isn't run? `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions` ?

Comment: I have disabled javascript in the browser, so I believe it is not executed

Comment: Yeah so the input of type image will send the coordinates where it was clicked.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.image.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering this question myself. If interested you can find more info http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.image.html

it states.

> The input element with a type attribute whose value is "image" represents either an image from which the UA enables a user to interactively select a pair of coordinates and submit the form, or alternatively a button from which the user can submit the form.